# Show equation has only one solution.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that the identity $e^{2x/3}(2+x^2)=1$ has only one solution in $\mathbb{R}$.

I thought we can show function is increasing, continuous and has positive and negative values. It’s easy to show that function is increasing and has positive value. Although, it seems obvious function is continuous I cannot prove it formally. Also I am interested how can I find negative value of the function. Can you help me?

Comment: It might help to graph the function on a graphing calculator: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2mcyf1l3cl

Comment: You could study the derivative of the function $f(x)=e^{2x/3}\!\left(2+x^2\right)-1\,.\;$

Comment: If you know that products and compositions of continuous functions are continuous, then you can easily show this function is continuous. The function is strictly positive since it is the product of two functions which are strictly positive on $\mathbb{R}$. Lastly, the function is not increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ as the graph Tom Kern has provided shows, though it is increasing on $x\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be $e^{2x/3}(2+x^2).$ Since composing, adding, or multiplying continuous functions results in a continuous function, $f$ is continuous. The derivative of $f(x)$ is $\frac{(2x^2+6x+4)e^{2x/3}}{3}.$ This derivative is zero when $x = -2$ or $x=-1.$ In both of those cases, $f(x)$ is greater than $1.$ Also, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $f(-5)$ is less than $1.$ By the Intermediate Value Theorem, a solution exists.

We prove the rest by contradiction. Assume that the equation has two solutions. Since the derivative of $f(x)$ has finitely many zeros, there are two solutions with no solutions between them. Therefore, there are two solutions $a$ and $b$ with $b>a$ and with no solutions between them such that $a$ is the greatest solution for which two solutions of this form exist.

Assume $f(x) < 1$ between two solutions. By Rolle's theorem, the derivative is $0$ between those two solutions, but the derivative is nonzero if $f(x) \leq 1.$ This is a contradiction. Therefore, between any two solutions, there must be a point where $f(x) \geq 1.$

Case $1$: $f(x) < 1$ between $a$ and $b.$  This is a contradiction.

Case $2$: $f(x) > 1$ between $a$ and $b.$  The derivative must be nonnegative at $a$ and nonpositive at $b$ since the function is greater than $1$ between $a$ and $b.$ The derivative at $b$ cannot be zero. If it is negative, since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there must be another solution greater than $b.$ Choose the smallest such solution and call it $d.$ There are no solutions between $b$ and $c.$ This is a contradiction of the definition of $a$ and $b.$ Therefore, the equation has only one solution.

Comment: Partial alternative.  The fact that the derivative exists, throughout the domain of the function proves that the function is continuous, throughout its domain.  A function has no derivative at any point of discontinuity.

Comment: The statement "Since f is made of continuous functions, its continuous" is not rigorous enough in my opinion. You need to specify the domain as well.